# How to move back to the current tab from any other tab in browser when a Webkit Notification is clicked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, coffeescript, dom-events, webkit-notifications

I have made a Webkit Desktop Notification for chat. when the user are not on the current chatting page (I mean on another tab), gets notification. Everything works fine as I want them to work :)

**Now what I need to do is when the user click on the appeared notification being on the other tab in browser, it will move back him to the chatting tab.**

***An Example, User chats on `MyAwesomeChat.example.com` and then moves to the Google.com and gets the notification there. Just as soon as he clicks on the notification it will take him to the `MyAwesomeChat.example.com`*****

Below I have written my code in a function. I add a 'click' `addEventListner` where I wanted to do the above thing, though clueless still.

```
desktopnotify:(chat) ->
                if (window.webkitNotifications)
                    havePermission = window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission()
                    if havePermission is 0 && @window_blur
                      if (!(chat.get('USER_MAIL')==LOCAL_DATA.username)) 
                      # 0 is PERMISSION_ALLOWED means the user 'allow's the permission to show desktop notification when asked
                        pLength = Participants.where({USER_MAIL:chat.get('USER_MAIL')}).length
                        userImage = Participants.where({USER_MAIL:chat.get('USER_MAIL')})[pLength-1].get('USER_IMAGE')
                        
                        if(userImage?)
                          notification = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification(userImage, chat.get('USER_MAIL'), chat.get('MESSAGE'))
                          
                        else
                          notification = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification('/images/no-image.jpeg', chat.get('USER_MAIL'), chat.get('MESSAGE'))
                        notification.addEventListener('display',()->
                          window.setTimeout((e)->
                            notification.cancel()
                          , 5000)
                        notification.addEventListener('click',()->
                            console.log('here i want to do the magic. it will take back user to the page where he was chatting')
                            )  
                        )
                        notification.show()
```

Any idea/help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a notification is bind with the window/tab that triggers it.  So you just need to tell it to focus on the binding tab upon clicking.

Add something like

```
notification.onclick = function() { 
window.focus();    // focus on binding window
this.cancel();     // close the notification on clicking it
};
```

So your final code should look like

```
    if (window.webkitNotifications)
                        havePermission = window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission()
                        if havePermission is 0 && @window_blur
                          if (!(chat.get('USER_MAIL')==LOCAL_DATA.username)) 
                          # 0 is PERMISSION_ALLOWED means the user 'allow's the permission to show desktop notification when asked
                            pLength = Participants.where({USER_MAIL:chat.get('USER_MAIL')}).length
                            userImage = Participants.where({USER_MAIL:chat.get('USER_MAIL')})[pLength-1].get('USER_IMAGE')

                            if(userImage?)
                              notification = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification(userImage, chat.get('USER_MAIL'), chat.get('MESSAGE'))

                            else
                              notification = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification('/images/no-image.jpeg', chat.get('USER_MAIL'), chat.get('MESSAGE'))
                            notification.addEventListener('display',()->
                              window.setTimeout((e)->
                                notification.cancel()
                              , 5000)
                            notification.addEventListener('click',()->
                                console.log('here i want to do the magic. it will take back user to the page where he was chatting')
                                )  
                            )

//--------------------------------------------------------------------//

                            notification.onclick = function() { 
                            window.focus();
                            this.cancel();
                            };

//--------------------------------------------------------------------//

                            notification.show()
```

Cheers!!

Comment: @FrOzenFyr
Hey,I didn't know about the binding part. It works :)
Thanks a lot man, appreciated.

Comment: Hey friend, I tried to do that as soon as I saw your answer. But it prompts 'requires 15 reputation'. :(
I'm new here so will quickly do a research on how to collect reputations and as soon as I get the sufficient I'll do everything you wanted above. :)

Comment: @the.big.lebowski: You can read about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) and a little about voting [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).  By the way,  if you mark my answer accepted,  you will receive +2 rep.

Comment: Cheers! stay around to find hundreds of questions on which you can give answers to collect reputation.  You can ask questions to get rep. too.